# How to declare MySQL valriable in pentaho-data-integration outside of the SQL query?

Tags: mysql, pentaho-data-integration

I have a dummy query like:

```
SET @cn1 = '';SET @rn1 = 1;SET @mdt = '';SET @scan = '';

SELECT 
@rn1 := test value,
@cn1 := testvalue,
@mdt := testvalue

from dual;
```

In this query I've declared variables outside of MySQL which is not supported by **pentaho ETL**, as per my requirement I cannot declare these variables within the query as it is showing wrong rank for every result set.

Based on this scenario, how do I declare MySQL variables outside of the query in pentaho?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Execute SQL script step along with Execute for each row AND variable substitution options.

The way it works is the question marks (?) in the script will be substituted for the Parameters listed in the step in the order they appear, and the Script will run N times, N will be the number of rows reaching the step.

[image]